# How to make a proper two-way communication with xbees

Tags: arduino, communication, xbee

So i've two xbees on two adafruit xbee FTDI adapters connected to two arduinos. I configured one to be a Coordinator AT and the other one End Device AT.

I give you the code for each arduino and each corresponding xbee.

Coordinator Arduino MEGA 2560+xbee s2

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial xbee(52,49);

void setup()  {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Serial on coordinator working");
  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  xbee.begin(9600);
  xbee.println("SoftwareSerial on coordinator working!");
}



void loop()                     // run over and over again
{
  xbee.print("hey");
  delay(5000);
  if (xbee.available()) {
      Serial.print((char)xbee.read());
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
      xbee.print((char)Serial.read());
  }
  delay(100);

}
```

End Device arduino UNO R3+xbee s2

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial xbee(2,3);

void setup()  {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Serial on end device working");
  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  xbee.begin(9600);
  xbee.println("SoftwareSerial on end device working!");
}



void loop()                     // run over and over again
{

  if (xbee.available()) {
      Serial.print((char)xbee.read());
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
      xbee.print((char)Serial.read());
  }
  delay(1000);
  xbee.print("hey(from end device)");
  delay(1000);
}
```

My problem is that while the end device can receive messages from the coordinator, the coordinator does not receive any messages even the message in the setup loop and i wanna make this work so i can have proper bi-directional communication.

I've checked the rx/tx pins even switched them on the fly but that doesnt seem to fix it.

any clues are welcome!

Comment: What's the value of `SC-Scan Channel` parameter in both devices ?

Comment: It seems that your coordinator didn't scan all channels available !!